# Unable to create manifest file in Xcode for iOS4 wireless distribution

Tags: xcode, ios4, distribution, manifest, wireless

I followed the steps provided in apple developer documentation for wireless distribution, as written below:

***In Xcode, you create an app archive using the “Build > Build and Archive” menu item. Then, in the Archived Applications source in Xcode's Organizer, select the app and click the “Share Application…” button. Then click the “Distribute for Enterprise…” button. You’ll be asked to provide information for the manifest file, which Xcode creates. See below, for information about the manifest file.***

When I click on “Distribute for Enterprise…” button, nothing happens. I mean, it does not ask anything. I have used an Adhoc distribution profile and have selected Device 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

> I have used an Adhoc distribution
>   profile and have selected Device 4.0.
>   Please suggest, where am I doing
>   mistake.

You can't use an Adhoc distribution, you need to make a Distribution Provisioning Profile to sign your app.  Check here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

From apple:  To successfully build your application in Xcode for in-house distribution, you will need to create and download an Enterprise Distribution Provisioning Profile. These are different than the Development Provisioning Profiles that were used earlier in that Apple will only recognize applications as being ready for distribution if they contain this Distribution Provisioning Profile.

Answer (score 0):

You are a member of the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) aren't you?

Comment: yes, I am a member of enterprise program. How this is related to my question?